# Adding extra line with JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-4

basically I want this to be replicated when the add button (last div) is clicked, but add on a _1 to the name also

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-2">Size</div>
         <div class="col-lg-3">
             {{ Form::select('size', $sizes, null, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
         </div>

        <div class="col-sm-1">Colour</div>
         <div class="col-lg-2">
             {{ Form::select('colour', $colours, null, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-1">Stock</div>
          <div class="col-lg-2">
              <input type="text" name="stock" class="form-control">
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-1">
          <!--- WHEN THIS IS CLICKED ----->
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="add"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add</a>
          </div>
       </div>
```

That whole form-group I want to show again when the add button is clicked, adding a underscore and a number to the name also to stop duplicate entries.

So something using jQuery I think should do this, but been a jQuery newbie I'm not sure what to write.

So on the click of the add button it needs to show the whole form-group div again underneath the one already there, but also add to the name attribute a underscore and a number to stop duplicate entries when I save to a DB.

Comment: Your question could use some improvement.  Don't assume that the reader has as much knowledge of your puzzle as you do.  Read the question again and see if it makes sense to someone coming at the problem cold.

Comment: When you say add form-group, are you talking about the content inside the form-group or does it include the form-group tag as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should copy the block and append the new copy to the body, with the name of the outer-most div set to ...a_x
If I get the question right that is what you want

```
 var  x = 0;
    $("#add").click(function(){ 
      x++;
      $('.form-group:first').clone().attr("name", "a_"+x).appendTo($('body'));
      alert(x);
    });
```

And a link from w3Schools http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_clone

Comment: Right ok got that working, but when I view source there's nothing there although it's cloned, but I need it to return HTML with the added stuff to the attr name field so I can save it to the database.

Comment: viewing the source doesn't show any javascript manipulated html, try "inspect element" to see it.